# Best DataStructure to implement Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: data-structures, graph, crud

How we can implement Excel spreadsheet with creation and deletion of rows and creation and deletion if cells, with also can modify data inside any cell.
I was looking for best data structure to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is little vague in my opinion. We do not have any information about the kind of operations that will be very frequent or even the amount of data that this DS is going to hold.

So assuming there can be fair amount of data. Also the operations are addition and deletion of rows and cells.

For excel spreadsheet, If I have to implement it with a custom Data Structure, I would take each row as a node of a linked list. This is helpful because as opposed to an array (n dimensional), the memory can be assigned in non contiguous manner. Also with that benefit, it will make adding and deletion of rows much easy.

Inside each node, we can have array of string to hold cell values and a Id field to hold the Id of the row.

The head node of the DS will have column names as value of its string array. So in a way each column is mapped to an index of the array.

To add a row: It will be an insert into the linked list. Make a new row and append in the end.
To delete a row: Same as deletion of node in a linked list.

To add/update a cell value: You basically know the row Id, you have column name so you can know the index of the column in the array from head node. So once you have the node corresponding to the row, access the index of string array to add/read/update/delete the value of cell.

In order to optimize node access you can keep indexes on the actual linked list to easily locate node by row Id. Some more optimizations would be store row-Id to node pointers mapping some where in auxiliary map or array so that inserting rows in between in also fast.

However I would re-iterate that implementation should be done on the use-case basis. If there are heavy column addition/deletion ops for example, it will be quite slow. There are different kind of trade-offs for each kind of use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way to go ahead with this is to simply use a JSON structure to hold each row. Column names as keys and the cell values as values. This handles null/empty values quite easily.

A spreadsheet is essentially similar to a table, changes can be made on any cell at any row. Hence going with a simple list structure would not be too bad. The downside to this is that deletion and insertion of in between rows is not performant. But the insertion of rows at end, which is the most common use case and modification of cells can be made quite easy.

To facilitate faster insertion and deletion a linked list structure will help, but it will affect random access adversely, so a simple list of json objects would be the better.